# Firestore int to dropdown list

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using Firestore to store the number of items for example.
Suppose I have in Firestore <plots 8>. How can create a dropdown list with Plot 1 through to 8.
For example if <plots 10> the list would return Plots 1 through to 10?

In Firestore I have

Plots 8

Within Flutter I would like a dropdown list with the following based on the number given.

Plot 1
Plot 2
Plot 3
Plot 4
Plot 5
Plot 6
Plot 7
Plot 8

Comment: Please edit your question, and make it understandable for others as well.

Comment: :/... Rather than down mark it just ask me to explain further, I am sorry Im not a elite coder. I came for help, is it any wonder people are afraid to ask for help these days with people like you..

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with a forEach loop on an Iterable :

```
List<int> plots = [];
int val = 0;

// In the build method
DropdownButton<int>(
  value: value,
  items: [
    for(var plot in plots)
      DropdownMenuItem<int>(child: Text("$plot"))
  ], 
  onChanged: (val) => setState(() => value = val)),
),
```

Comment: Thank you kindly, foreach loop was the term I needed. I will give it a go

Comment: You're welcome :) Comment again if you have further questions

Comment: I am a little confused, So for example I see List<String> plots []. Why is this not an int if I am going to be using a int from firestore.

Comment: Oh yeah my bad, I edited. I also annotated the type to make it safer. But really you can use any type.

Comment: List<String> plots = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'];
  int value ;                                                                                                                       Maybe I didnt explain myself enough. This works fine but all I will be suppling is a int from firestore Then I need to have from the start number to the end number like. 1 to 8. But I only want to supply 1 number. I suppose I could split the string from firestore but that just means I have more work in ifirestore